# Saving image to a folder not working on azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I am saving image files to a folder in my application and saving its path in database . Image uploads working fine when I am running locally and its path is also storing.When I deployed it on azure it gives an error that " An error occurred while processing your request ". I have two tables in my database . First one where text is saved is working fine on azure but image upload thrown this error.

[image: Text saved correctly]

[image]
[image]

I am using [this](http://cpratt.co/file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc-with-view-models/) code to upload image and its works fine when I am running locally.
Need help ?

When I made customs error mode off it gives this error

Comment: Some more detail would be good. How have you deployed to Azure - as  an Azure Website, a Cloud Service, a VM ? Do you know how to retrieve the logs so you can see more detail about the error ?

Comment: I deployed as an azure website

Comment: No i just follow this link to deploy to azure with database first  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/publish-to-azure

Answer (score 2):

Code you use for uploading images won't work in Azure. Just imagine how this should work if you scale up nubmer of instances. 
You should use Azure blob storage to upload files in Azure. 
You can google for good tutorial, but to make a long story short you should do the following:

1.) Create Azure Storage Account at manage.windowsazure.com

2.) Setup storage connection string (you can get AccountKey from you storage account)

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storagesample;AccountKey=nYV0gln9fT7bvY+rxu2iWAEyzPNITGkhM88J8HUoyofpK7C8fHcZc2kIZp6cKgYRUM74lHI84L50Iau1+9hPjB==" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In Your code

3.) Add following namespaces

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
```

4.) Initialize Storage Connection

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
```

5.) Create container, if it diesn't exist

```
// Retrieve a reference to a container. 
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

// Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
container.CreateIfNotExists();
container.SetPermissions(
    new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = 
    BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
```

6.) Specify object name

> // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob". CloudBlockBlob
>   blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

7.) Upload fata

> MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
>   Image img =
>   Image.FromStream(model.ImageUpload.InputStream);
>   img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
>
> // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from 
>   file. 
>       blockBlob.UploadFromStream(ms.ToArray());

Code you linked to will look like this:

> [HttpPost] [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] public ActionResult
>   Create(ImageViewModel model) {
>       var validImageTypes = new string[]
>       {
>           "image/gif",
>           "image/jpeg",
>           "image/pjpeg",
>           "image/png"
>       }
>
> ```
> if (model.ImageUpload == null || model.ImageUpload.ContentLength == 0)
> {
>     ModelState.AddModelError("ImageUpload", "This field is required");
> }
> else if (!imageTypes.Contains(model.ImageUpload.ContentType))
> {
>     ModelState.AddModelError("ImageUpload", "Please choose either a GIF, JPG or PNG image.
> }
>
> if (ModelState.IsValid)
> {
>     var image = new Image
>     {
>         Title = model.Title,
>         AltText = model.AltText,
>         Caption = model.Caption
>     }
>
>     if (model.ImageUpload != null && model.ImageUpload.ContentLength > 0)
>     {
> ```
>
> CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
>       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
>       CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
>   // Retrieve a reference to a container. 
>       CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("uploads");

```
// Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
container.CreateIfNotExists();
container.SetPermissions(
    new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = 
    BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
```

> blockBlob =
>   container.GetBlockBlobReference(model.ImageUpload.FileName);
>
> ```
>         var imageUrl = blockBlob.Uri;
> ```
>
> MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
>   Image img =
>   Image.FromStream(model.ImageUpload.InputStream);
>   img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
>
> // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from 
>   file. 
>       blockBlob.UploadFromStream(ms.ToArray()); 
>               image.ImageUrl = imageUrl;
>           }
>
> ```
>     db.Create(image);
>     db.SaveChanges();
>     return RedirectToAction("Index");
> }
>
> return View(model); }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In Azure writing to local physical paths are not permitted. So you need to replace your saving functionality to write the bits to an external storage system like Azure Blob Storage or any other relevant storage system.

If you are looking for a temporary local storage to do some quick processing before the actual saving, then you can make use of Azure Local Storage